# SQL Join and exclude / filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got an SQL query which joins 2 tables, I'm trying to filter rows which match a condition, then filter out the results if the same condition matches with different values, but the last WHERE clause seems to be ignored:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblclients.firstname, tblclients.lastname, tblclients.email
FROM
    tblclients
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM tblhosting
        WHERE tblhosting.packageid IN (75,86)
    ) tblhosting ON tblclients.id = tblhosting.userid
WHERE 
    tblhosting.packageid NOT IN (76,77,78)
```

The idea being to get a list of customers which have a certain package (ID 75 and 86), then exclude/take out any results/customers which also have another package as well as 75/86 (ID 76,77,78 etc). It's not excluding those results though at all, tried numerous variations here on Stackoverflow, where am I going wrong please?

Comment: Please move `tblhosting.packageid NOT IN (76,77,78)` to `LEFT JOIN` after `tblhosting ON tblclients.id = tblhosting.userid`

Comment: Remove the complete outer WHERE

Comment: @MegaTron - Already in Inner query records are filtered to `packageid(75,86)` then what is the use of this filter in `tblhosting.packageid NOT IN (76,77,78)` `ON` codition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `LEFT JOIN` at all in this case.  I would use a combination of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to get your desired results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email
  FROM tblclients c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM tblhosting h
                WHERE h.userid = c.id
                  AND h.packageid IN (75,86))
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM tblhosting h
                    WHERE h.userid = c.id
                      AND h.packageid IN (76,77,78))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! Very neat and easy to extend too!

Answer (score 4):

Add it to the `join` condition itself. When you have a `where` clause filter your `join` would be treated as `inner join`.

```
tblhosting ON tblclients.id = tblhosting.userid and tblhosting.packageid NOT IN (76,77,78)
```

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT tblclients.firstname, tblclients.lastname, tblclients.email
FROM
    tblclients
LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT userid
        FROM tblhosting
        WHERE tblhosting.packageid IN (75,86,76,77,78)
    group by  userid
   having count(1) = count(case when packageid IN (75,86) then 1 end)
) tblhosting  
ON tblclients.id = tblhosting.userid
```